# how to use Twit's Typescript definitions; Callback function not assignable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm just getting started into Node and typescript. I'm an experienced Java engineer and have done front end work, but it's been mostly copy-paste-modify without fully understanding all the javascript. Now I'm trying to get deeper into Node, JS and Typescript, and think I have jumped too far ahead without understanding what all is going on.  This is just a small personal project. I would like to use classes and liked what TS offered but it seems to introduce more complexity and problems than it solved, so maybe it's not worth it.

I'm trying to use the Twit package to just read tweets. Had it working fine in plain js before trying to convert it to TS. This was my working js:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var Twit = require('twit');

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         '..'
  , consumer_secret:      '..'
  , access_token:         '..'
  , access_token_secret:  '..'
})

var options = { screen_name: 'TwitterUser',
                count: 200 };

T.get('statuses/user_timeline', options , function(err, data) {
  // it comes latest first; I want earliest first
  data.reverse();
  console.log(data[0]);

  // try to filter out alerts only
  var alerts = _.filter(data, function(tweet){
    return (tweet.text.indexOf('#alert') > -1) ||
          (tweet.text.indexOf('#ALERT') > -1);
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < alerts.length ; i++) {
    console.log(alerts[i].created_at + '  ' + alerts[i].text);
  }
})
```

here is the Typescript version:

```
import { IncomingMessage } from "http";
import _ from "lodash";
import Twit from "twit";

export class TwitterListener {

    getlatestTweets() {
        const T = new Twit({
            consumer_key:         '..'
          , consumer_secret:      '..'
          , access_token:         '..'
          , access_token_secret:  '..'
        })

        const options = { screen_name: 'TwitterUser',
                count: 200 };

        T.get('statuses/user_timeline', options, function(err, result: Response, data: IncomingMessage) {
            // it comes latest first; I want earliest first
            data.reverse();
            console.log(data[0]);
            
            // try to filter out alerts only
            const alerts = _.filter(data, function(tweet: Twit.Twitter.Status) {
                return (tweet.text.indexOf('#alert') > -1) ||
                    (tweet.text.indexOf('#ALERT') > -1);
            });
            
            for (let i = 0; i < alerts.length ; i++) {
                console.log(alerts[i].created_at + '  ' + alerts[i].text);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The biggest problem is on the callback for the get user timeline. The VS Code linter says 'Argument of type (whatever I've tried) is not assignable to parameter of type Callback. The Type Docs at [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/twit/index.d.ts) say this should be a Callback like so:

```
export interface Callback {
    (err: Error, result: Response, response: IncomingMessage): void;
}
```

Which is why I tried to change it to that. I thought from the plain js version where the callback is `function(err, data)` and data is an array of tweets/Statuses that it might be something like `function(err:Error, data: any[])` or `function(err, data: Array<Twit.Twitter.Status>)`, which I also tried, but got the same error. I have a feeling it's the syntax of how I'm defining this callback function, but can't figure out what.

I don't understand how the callback definition goes from `function(err, data)` to the Callback type with the result and response. What am I missing?

Comment: The error is that the `Response` types are different, they just have the same name. Please note that explicitly specifying callback parameter types is a bad practice. Callback parameter types should be inferred for correctness.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks for your reply; you said "explicitly specifying callback parameter types is a bad practice"; I'm confused, I thought strongly typing was one of the main points of Typescript? How should this look with the callback parameter types inferred as you suggest?

Comment: Strong typing is the point. Specifying a type known to the compiler isn't increasing the strength of your types. `[1, 2, 3].map(x => x + x)` is strongly typed in TypeScript. All of the types are known and verified.  `[1, 2, 3].map((x: number) => x + x)` doesn't increase the strength of types. However, in many circumstances, specifying the type of the parameter can reduce type information because the type specified may be a subtype and, critically, if the type was _not_ known the compiler you would be suppressing a `noImplicitAny` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is - like mentioned in the comment by Aluan Haddad - that the type of the second parameter of your function is not compatible to the specified type of the callback function in the Twit package.

The type of the callback function is this:

```
export interface Callback {
    (err: Error, result: Response, response: IncomingMessage): void;
}
```

I think the source of your confusion is, that the Response type in this definition does not refer to the built-in Response type, but the Twit package overwrites (shadows) this definition with this one:

```
export type Response = object;
```

This type definition is a bit confusing and at least the naming should reflect that its a Twitter response and not the built-in definition that is describing the [Fetch API response](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0c08138490696c8fee4114f1a8dae0f74caa4715/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L12622) built into the browser.

To fix your problem, you have to import this Response definition from the Twit package or refer to it via "Twit.Response". Importing it into your own file, will shadow the built-in definition there too and you can refer to the "Response" type of the Twit package.

```
import Twit, {Response} from "twit"
```

I want to remark that the strongly typed parameters of your function are NOT the problem, instead they have lead to you questioning your code. Without the types in your own function, you wouldn't have seen a problem and - maybe - never would have seen that there is a misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks! I understood from Aluan Haddad that it was the wrong Response type, but I don't even understand yet how to import the right one. Now my problem is how to get the actual twitter data out, because the Response and IncomingMessage types don't appear to contain any actual twitter data. The IncomingMessage properties look like more basic http things, and Response is just a plain Object. What am I missing?

Comment: If you look in your linked DefinitlyTyped documentation, you'll see that this is just how it works: IncomingMessage is imported from 'http' and Response is just a renamed 'object' type.

Answer (score -2):

After looking at [twit's documentation](https://github.com/ttezel/twit#tgetpath-params-callback) I realized the callback accept three (3) parameters `err - an error`, `data - arrays of tweets` and `response - response object from twitter`. The reason the js version worked is because of the loosely typed nature of javascript.